derived class is being unidentified reference to typeinfo of base class
So i am getting this error upon compiling and linking my excutable
remote: [compile] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/interpreter.dir/src/Parser/Parser.cpp.o: in function `Expr::Expr()':
remote: [compile] Parser.cpp:(.text._ZN4ExprC2Ev[_ZN4ExprC5Ev]+0x9): undefined reference to `vtable for Expr'
remote: [compile] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/interpreter.dir/src/Parser/Parser.cpp.o: in function `Expr::~Expr()':
remote: [compile] Parser.cpp:(.text._ZN4ExprD2Ev[_ZN4ExprD5Ev]+0x9): undefined reference to `vtable for Expr'
remote: [compile] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/interpreter.dir/src/Parser/Parser.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI5Unary[_ZTI5Unary]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Expr'
remote: [compile] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/interpreter.dir/src/Parser/Parser.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI7Literal[_ZTI7Literal]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Expr'
remote: [compile] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/interpreter.dir/src/Parser/Parser.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI8Grouping[_ZTI8Grouping]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Expr'
remote: [compile] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/interpreter.dir/src/Parser/Parser.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI6Binary[_ZTI6Binary]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Expr'
remote: [compile] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
remote: [compile] gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/interpreter.dir/build.make:161: interpreter] Error 1
remote: [compile] gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/interpreter.dir/all] Error 2
remote: [compile] gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

in Parser.ccp these are the functions i am instantanizing the derived class as such in the following functions
Expr* Parser::primary() {

    Expr* expr;

    if(match(FALSE)) {
        expr = new Literal(false);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
        return expr;
    }
    if(match(TRUE)) {
        expr = new Literal(true);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
        return expr;
    }
    if(match(NIL)) {
        expr = new Literal(nullptr);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
        return expr;
    }

    if(match(NUMBER, STRING)) {
        expr = new Literal(previous()->literal);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
        return expr;
    }

    if(match(LEFT_PAREN)) {
        expr = expression(); // recursively calls all of the exprs in between the parenthesis
        consume(RIGHT_PAREN, "Expect ')' after expression");
        Expr* groupedExpr = new Grouping(expr);
        expressions.push_back(groupedExpr);
        return groupedExpr;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

Expr* Parser::unary() {
    if(match(BANG, MINUS)) {
        Token* oprator = previous();
        Expr* right = unary();
        Expr* expr = new Unary(oprator, right);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
        return expr;
    }

    return primary();
}

Expr* Parser::factor() {
    Expr* expr = unary();

    while(match(SLASH, STAR)) {
        Token* oprator = previous();
        Expr* right = unary();
        expr = new Binary(expr, oprator, right);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
    }

    return expr;
}

Expr* Parser::term() {
    Expr* expr = factor();

    while(match(MINUS, PLUS)) {
        Token* oprator = previous();
        Expr* right = factor();
        expr = new Binary(expr, oprator, right);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
    }

    return expr;
}

Expr* Parser::comparison() {
    Expr* expr = term();

    while(match(GREATER, GREATER_EQUAL, LESS, LESS_EQUAL)) {
        Token* oprator = previous();
        Expr* right = term();
        expr = new Binary(expr, oprator, right);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
    }

    return expr;
}

Expr* Parser::equality() {
    Expr* left = comparison();


    while(match(BANG_EQUAL, EQUAL_EQUAL)) {
        Token* oprator = previous();
        Expr* right = comparison();
        Expr* expr = new Binary(left, oprator, right);
        expressions.push_back(expr);
        return expr;
    }

    return left;
}

i am pushing the Expr objects into an expressions vector so i could dynamically delete the pointers in main.cpp after printing them to the console.
i have the derived and base classes in Expr.hpp and this is how they are implemented:
#ifndef EXPR_H
#define EXPR_H

#include "../Scanner/Token.hpp"

class Expr {
    public:
        class Visitor { //Interface
            public:
                // virtual string visitAssignExpr(const class Assign& expr) const = 0;
                virtual string visitBinaryExpr(const class Binary& expr) const = 0;
                // virtual string visitCallExpr(const class Call& expr) const = 0;
                // virtual string visitGetExpr(const class Get& expr) const = 0;
                virtual string visitGroupingExpr(const class Grouping& expr) const = 0;
                virtual string visitLiteralExpr(const class Literal& expr) const = 0;
                // virtual string visitLogicalExpr(const class Logical& expr) const = 0;
                // virtual string visitSetExpr(const class Set& expr) const = 0;
                // virtual string visitSuperExpr(const class Super& expr) const = 0;
                // virtual string visitThisExpr(const class This& expr) const = 0;
                virtual string visitUnaryExpr(const class Unary& expr) const = 0;
                // virtual string visitVariableExpr(const class Variable& expr) const = 0;
                virtual ~Visitor() = default; 
        };

        virtual string accept(const Visitor& visitor) const;

        virtual ~Expr() = default;
};

class Binary : public Expr {
    public:
        Binary(Expr* left, Token* oprator, Expr* right)
            : left(left), oprator(oprator), right(right) {}
        ~Binary() override = default;

        string accept(const Visitor& visitor) const override {
            return visitor.visitBinaryExpr(*this);
        }

        Expr* left;
        Token* oprator;
        Expr* right; 
};

class Grouping : public Expr {
    public:
        Grouping(Expr* expression)
            : expression(expression) {}
        ~Grouping() override = default;

        string accept(const Visitor& visitor) const override {
            return visitor.visitGroupingExpr(*this);
        }

        Expr* expression; 
};

class Literal : public Expr {
    public:
        using T = std::variant<int, double, std::string, bool, nullptr_t>;
        Literal(T value)
            : value(value) {}
        ~Literal() override = default;
        
        string accept(const Visitor& visitor) const override {
            return visitor.visitLiteralExpr(*this);
        }

        T value;
};

class Unary : public Expr { 
    public: 
        Unary(Token* oprator, Expr* right) 
            : oprator(oprator), right(right) {}
        ~Unary() override = default;

        string accept(const Visitor& visitor) const override {
            return visitor.visitUnaryExpr(*this);
        }

        Token* oprator;
        Expr* right;
};

#endif

I intially did not override the destructor in the derived classes so i later on did so, and. was expecting those were the root cause of the issue but turns out they aren't so i am a bit confused to why this keeps on happening.
I would really appreciate any help on this matter.

Please reduce the code and post a [mre]. Where do you define Expr::accept?
